# PHP can't run matlab function

Tags: php, matlab

I want run Matlab function from PHP
I run this code on MAC, local server using MAMP and Matlab R2016b.
this is my php code:

```
exec ($command = "/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/Contents/MacOS/StartMATLAB computeSIFT.m ");
```

When i execute that code it's works and Matlab can open 'copmputeSIFT.m' file.
But when i want to call Matlab and call 'computeSIFT()' function, there is nothing happened.I think there is no mistake on my code. 
this is the code:

```
exec=($command = "/Applications/MATLAB_R2016b.app/Contents/MacOS/StartMATLAB nojvm -nodesktop -nodisplay -r \"computeSIFT()\"");
```

I already search on google, copy paste their code and the result is the same when there is '-r' on my command.Is there some different syntax on matlab R2016b?

Comment: Do both commands work when you execute them from your local Bash terminal?

Comment: sorry i had a mistake on typing my second code, there is no = after exec.
i run both code, there is no error, but there is nothing happened on my second code.